# Image width 100% - scaleMode flex mobile

Tags: image, apache-flex, mobile, actionscript, scale

I have a view in my flex mobile application, in which I have a lot of pictures which should shown in VGroup. The pictures are 851x315, they should have width="100%". About and under the picture are white areas. I want put the next picture direct under the picture without any white areas.

Here a screenshot (I have scrolled on the screen, so that's better to see):

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also, show some code; there are multiple things that could cause the behavior you're seeing, depending on what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the VGroup gap and padding to zero.

```
<s:VGroup gap="0" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingRight="0" paddingLeft="0">
   ...
</s:VGroup>
```